# Right and left fixed image position with css

Tags: html, css, fixed

I want to put a left and a right fixed image, and I don't know why the right one only goes to the right when is not fixed. This is my code:

```
<img src="img/leftImage.jpg" id="leftImage" />
<img src="img/rightImage.jpg" id="rightImage" />
```

and my css:

```
#leftImage{
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#rightImage{
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? thank you!

**EDIT**

this is my index.html:

```
<body ng-cloak>
    <img src="img/leftImage.jpg" id="leftImage" />
    <div id="homescreen" class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/rightImage.jpg" id="rightImage" />
    <footer></footer>
</body>
```

and the CSS that I have:

```
body {
  background: url(/img/background.jpg) repeat fixed;
  background-position-y: -50px;
  background-position-x: -50px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#homescreen {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

container is a bootstrap class.

Comment: it's all fine that you've done. i think your css is overridden by other styles. can you share all your CSS?

Comment: Seems to be working properly.

Comment: I've just added more code about the problem.

Comment: still it works fine. there's nothing wrong. can you create a fiddle with all your HTML, CSS and JS codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to add the value for `top`

do something like this:

```
#leftImage {
  top: 20px; /* your required value */
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#rightImage {
  top: 20px; /* your required value */
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: yes! doing that solved my problem! I thought that I may not need that. thank you!

Comment: you'll always need that because if you don't use it, by default it take position according to the content placement in the HTML. and even if it works for you, it won't be crossbrowser. so always keep this in mind. don't forget to accept the answer and upvote too

Comment: I've already upvoted and accepted it. Thank you for the advice, I'm a developer, not a designer, so all this comments are very useful for me!

Comment: I'm a developer but not Designer so someday you might be of my help. you owe me one :D

Comment: you may be able to help me with something related to the question. At the moment the footer is overlaying the left and right bar, and I want the to extend until the footer starts. I tried with bottom property but it does not work, do you know what might be happening?

Comment: well, i didn't understand the question. i think it's better to post it as a new post in clear manner. as far as i understand, i think it's because you've used `height: 100%` for the image, if you're talking about those right and left fixed image. remove the height and bottom property will work

Comment: Yes, I tried removing it but it does not fits well. I've just posted again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43442012/100-height-image-with-fixed-topbar-and-a-footer-not-fixed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141840/discussion-between-lucian-and-motomine).