# 100% height image with fixed topbar and a footer (not fixed)

Tags: html, css

I have a topbar that it's fixed and a footer that appears when you scrolldown. I want to put to images with 100% but the problem is that the footer is overlaying them when you scroll down, how can I avoid that?

this is my code:

```
<body ng-cloak>
    <topbar></topbar>
    <img src="img/leftImage.jpg" id="leftImage" />
    <div id="homescreen" class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/rightImage.jpg" id="rightImage" />
    <footer></footer>
</body>

body {
  background: url(/img/background.jpg) repeat fixed;
  background-position-y: -50px;
  background-position-x: -50px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

#homescreen {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#leftImage{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#rightImage{
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I know that if I put bottom: 0 the height property will do it anyway. If I wasn't clear please ask me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

flexbox can help you acheive a sticky footer:

HTML:

```
<body class="flexbox-wrapper">
  <main class="page-wrapper">
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <div class="content">CONTENT</div>
  </main>
  <footer>FOOTER</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS reset*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* styling*/
header, footer, .content {
  padding: 25px;
}
header {
  background: #eee;
}
footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* needed code for sticky footer */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.flexbox-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/dreiv/pen/bgaBam

with this the footer will be on the bottom of the page by default or at the bottom of your content, if the content is bigger than the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position: relative; z-index: 1` for `footer`

since your right and left block is fixed, it will be at the top so you need to make footer above it. increase the value of `z-index` for footer if it's lower than side blocks.

for `#leftImage` and `#rightImage` remove `height` and use value of `bottom`

for example, here is the code for one block

```
#leftImage {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  bottom: 20px; /* same as the height of footer */
  position: fixed;
}

footer {
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't want to overlay the image, I want the image to extend until the footer starts, If the footer has 50 px of height I want the image to have 50% of bottom, so they don't overlay.